# How to get the size of an iFrame and set the content based on that

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wanted to use Filler Banners in my Ad Network if there are no other Banners available. I wanted to load them from /adload.html and i used that code in there:

```
<html>
    <body>
<script language="JavaScript">
if(top.location != self.location){
$(document).ready(function() {
// when to show the 468x60px div
    if($(window).width() == 468) && ($(window).length() == 60 {
        $('#468x60').show();
    } else {
        $('#468x60').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 728px div
    if($(window).width() == 728) {
        $('#728').show();
    } else {
        $('#728').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 250px div
    if($(window).width() == 250) {
        $('#250').show();
    } else {
        $('#250').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 200px div
    if($(window).width() == 200) {
        $('#200').show();
    } else {
        $('#200').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 336px div
    if($(window).width() == 336) {
        $('#336').show();
    } else {
        $('#336').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 300x250px div
    if($(window).width() == 300) && ($(window).length() == 250) {
        $('#300x250').show();
    } else {
        $('#300x250').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 120px div
    if($(window).width() == 120) {
        $('#120').show();
    } else {
        $('#120').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 160px div
    if($(window).width() == 160) {
        $('#160').show();
    } else {
        $('#160').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 300x600 div
    if($(window).width() == 300) && ($(window).length() == 600) {
        $('#300x600').show();
    } else {
        $('#300x600').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 240px div
    if($(window).width() == 240) {
        $('#240').show();
    } else {
        $('#240').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 970x90px div
    if($(window).width() == 970) && ($(window).length() == 90) {
        $('#970x90').show();
    } else {
        $('#970x90').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 970x250px div
    if($(window).width() == 970) && ($(window).length() == 250) {
        $('#970x250').show();
    } else {
        $('#970x250').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 320x100px div
    if($(window).width() == 320) && ($(window).length() == 100) {
        $('#320x100').show();
    } else {
        $('#320x100').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 320x50px div
    if($(window).width() == 320) && ($(window).lenth() == 50) {
        $('#320x50').show();
    } else {
        $('#320x50').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 600px div
    if($(window).width() == 600) {
        $('#600').show();
    } else {
        $('#600').hide();
    }
    //when to show the 468x120px div
    if($(window).width() == 468) && ($(window).length() == 120) {
        $('#468x120').show();
    } else {
        $('#728').hide();
    }
});
};
</script>
<div id="468x60">468x60</div>
<div id="728">728x90</div>
<div id="250">250x250</div>
<div id="200">200x200</div>
<div id="336">336x280</div>
<div id="300x250">300x250</div>
<div id="120">120x600</div>
<div id="160">160x600</div>
<div id="300x600">300x600</div>
<div id="240">240x400</div>
<div id="970x90">970x90</div>
<div id="970x250">970x250</div>
<div id="320x100">320x100</div>
<div id="320x50">320x50</div>
<div id="600">600x200</div>
<div id="468x120">462x120</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the Site displays every Code but does not hide the ones it is supposed to hide. I wanted it to detect the iFrame Size and display the right one.

The Function to implement the iFrame would be this one:

```
function r(t, e, i) {
            //console.log(e);
            if (e.data) {
                var n = p.config.click_url + "/?" + e.data.link,
                    o = '<div id="' + e.data.hash_id + '" class="adflex-b-reset adflex-b-box adflex-dsa">\n                <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; padding: 0; margin: 0;"> \n                    <a href="' + n + '" class="adflex-b-reset" target="_blank">\n                    <img class="adflex-b-reset" \n                         src="' + e.data.img_url + '"\n                         style="width: ' + e.data.img_width + 'px; max-width: 100% !important;">\n                    </a>\n                    ' + f(i) + "\n                    </div>\n                </div>";
                document.getElementById(t).innerHTML += o
            } else /*1 == e.params.third_party_status && e.params.third_party_code &&*/ (document.getElementById(t).innerHTML += /*e.params.third_party_code*/"<iframe src='//internal.webadtopia.com/adload.html' scrolling='no' style='width:"+e.banner_size[0]+"px; height:"+e.banner_size[1]+"px; border:0px; padding:0; overflow:hidden; background-color: transparent;'></iframe>", p.runJs(t))
        }
```

Can someone tell me where It went wrong?

Comment: There's parens errors in the first 468x60 block at the top, this makes the script abort (and thus not hide anything). Please always check the browser console for errors first.

Comment: Here's a jQuery free rewrite: https://jsfiddle.net/qp60xtcf/

Comment: Don't use JS for this - it leads to a mess of code which is more difficult than it needs to be to maintain. Just use CSS media queries on the content within the iframe.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how would i do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries